# Import 'transport' error in asyncio attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a discord bot, but I get the following weird error where it can not import `asyncio.Transport`, although I am able to use it normally outside this code.

The code:

```
import asyncio
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 19, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\inspect.py", line 36, in <module>
    import dis
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\dis.py", line 3, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 34, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import (
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http_parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .base_protocol import BaseProtocol
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\base_protocol.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .tcp_helpers import tcp_nodelay
  File "C:\Users\A.Gawish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py", line 20, in <module>
    def tcp_keepalive(transport: asyncio.Transport) -> None:
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'Transport'
```

Comment: I don't think `asyncio.Transport` was introduced until 3.7, going by the `asyncio` documentation, it doesn't appear there until 3.7

Comment: it exists in the library, I checked, also I can use it outside the scope of this program.

Comment: The error occurs on the first line of your program so the rest of the code is immaterial.  What do you mean by saying you can "use it outside the scope of this program?"  How are you launching the program, versus how are you using it successfully otherwise?

Comment: I use the command: `python dis.py` to run it, but when I launch python in command shell and I do: `import asyncio` then use in anyway `asyncio.Transport` it works fine.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filename was `dis.py`, which is used in another [module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/dis.py). I resolved a similar issue by ensuring the filename is different from any other existing files in Lib

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your error messages, it is indicating Python36. If Transport in asyncio was only released in Python37, you need to change the pathing in whatever program you're using to write the code in as it's looking at Python36.

Testing it as the command prompt would show that your system sees Python37 but your code doesn't. Fix the pathing and it should work then.

Comment: I don't even have Python37 on my computer, and the command prompt launch python 36 `Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.